# What kind of chance is the "a chance" in "that's almost as good a chance as we have in New York"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Here is the paragraph:

> "Oh, I never heard of such nonsense," complained Sue, with magnificent scorn. "What have old ivy leaves to do with your getting well? And you used to love that vine so, you naughty girl. Don't be a goosey. Why the doctor told me this morning that your chances for getting well real soon were - let's see exactly what he said - he said the chances were ten to one! Why,  that's almost as good **a chance** as we have in New York when we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building.

It is from [*The Last Leaf*](https://americanliterature.com/author/o-henry/short-story/the-last-leaf).

Comment: Are you sure that's a sentence? It's missing a few things. What's the context?

Comment: Why, the doctor told me this morning that your chances for getting well real soon were - let's see exactly what he said - he said the chances were ten to one! Why, that's almost as good a chance as we have in New York when we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building. Try to take some broth now, and let Sudie go back to her drawing, so she can sell the editor man with it, and buy port wine for her sick child, and pork chops for her greedy self."

Comment: That phrase is a *time clause*, which is a type of *adverbial*. I'm not sure that will satisfy you though. What's your real question?

Comment: If it is a time clause, what will define "a chance"?  Or what kind of chance is this "a chance"? Does it make any sense if we say "we have a chance in New York when we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building"?

Comment: I feel it is supposed to be reworded in modern English like this: "In New York, we have a chance to ride on the street cars or walk past a new building.

Comment: @eric I think that "*we have a chance to ride on*" is quite different in meaning. In that use "chance" means "opportunity" while in the quote "chance" means "probability" or "risk", which is a very different sense of '"chance".

Comment: Are you really asking about its grammatical function, or its semantic role?

Comment: @BillJ, the title has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Sue is making a sardonic* comparison, pretending to quote the doctor. She is saying that the doctor said that the chances that you will get well soon are ten-to-one.
Then she says that's almost as good a chance as you have of escaping a bad fate when you ride on a streetcar or walk past a new building.
This is indirectly saying that riding streetcars and walking past buildings in New York are hazardous activities, with slightly better than a ten-to-one chance of not being injured. It seems likely, without more context, that the doctor didn't really say those things, but that Sue is making it up.

**So, don't feel too bad about being sick. New York is dangerous all the time.**

[AHD *sardonic*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sardonic)

1. Scornfully or cynically mocking: *a sardonic sense of humor.*

Comment: But I think the author is talking about the chance of getting well, not the chance of being sick.

Comment: Yes. Sue is saying you will likely get well. That likelihood is better than the likelihood of not being injured in everyday activities in New York.

Comment: I thing the irony, scorn, or sardonicism all comes from Sue, not the doctor

Comment: The  quoted text does not actually mention "escaping a bad fate " or anything of a similar meaning. This might be what Sue had in mind, but she does not say so in the given quote.. That lask renders the quote devoid of a clear, detailed meaning, IMO

Comment: @DavidSiegel  I agree. Sue is making fun of, maybe her younger sister? I modified the answer to reflect that. I don't think the meaning is unclear, though. She's saying the patient's chance of not recovering is comparable to the everyday risks of the city.

Comment: @DavidSiegel and Jack, have you read the story? Sue is the solicitous caretaker (doesn't say sister). She's not mocking or scornful; she's attempting an awkward joke to lighten the mood.

Comment: @AndyBonner The quote itself says "with magnificent scorn". There's no reason though, that one couldn't lighten the mood with some sarcastic scorn.

Comment: @AndyBonner I have not read the story, nor had i ever heard of it before I read this question. It is clear thar Sue is being scornful -- the quote says so. My point was that there is no reason to think that the **doctor** was being scornful or sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

As written I do not think that

> ... he said the chances were ten to one! Why, that's almost as good a chance as we have in New York when we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building.

has a clear meaning at all. It is not clear if the character "sue" is referring to the chance of going by safely, or to some other chance that will occur when walking or riding in New York. Such confusion could easily arise in off-0hand speech, so this dialog may be realistic, but it cannot be fully an accurately analyzed in terms of grammar.

> ... when we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building

indicates at what time or during what event the rest of the sentence or clause occurs, and so is a form of adverbial, as a comment says. But the text as given simply does not say what kind of chance is going to occur at that time. *A chance of what?* is never answered in the quote given.

Comment: But it is highly likely that, in New York, we ride on the street cars or walk past a new building.

Comment: @eric Yes, but is Sue referring to the chance of riding or walking past a new building or the chance of some dangerous accident, or some other chance she failed to make clear, such as the chance of seeing someone known?  Since Sue did not say, we cannot know what she meant.

Comment: So, the when-clause is useless, having nothing to do with a clear meaning of the sentence, or at least, having nothing to do with a clear meaning of the "a chance".

Comment: @Eric It seems to me that Sue's thought is not fully expressed, as spoken thoughts often are not, unless there is more in the context that was not quoted.  don't know if the author intended this or not.